# 3D-Animation plot with the hgtransform command in Matlab

Tags: matlab, animation, graphics, 3d

I continue to think of the possibilities for the 3d-animation (moving point along a curve). I have written the following code to try it using the hgtransform command but I do not understand why does not work.

```
 t = 0:pi/50:10*pi;
    x = sin(t);
    y = cos(t);
    z = t;
    ah = axes;
    set(ah,'XLim',[min(x) max(x)],'YLim',[min(y) max(y)],...
        'ZLim',[min(z) max(z)]);
    plot3(x,y,z,'Color','red');
    hold on;
    view(3);
    hpoint = line('XData',x(1),'YData',y(1),'ZData',z(1),'Color','black','Marker',...
        'o','MarkerSize',10,'MarkerFaceColor','black');
    ht = hgtransform('parent',ah);
    set(hpoint,'Parent',ht);

    for i=2:length(x)
        tx = x(i)-x(i-1);
        ty = y(i)-y(i-1);
        tz = z(i)-z(i-1);
        trans = makehgtform('translate',[tx ty tz]),      
        set(ht,'Matrix',trans);
        pause(0.01);
    end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to calculate `tx`, `ty`, and `tz` in your loop as follows:

```
tx = x(i)-x(1);  %# Note the 1 instead of i-1
ty = y(i)-y(1);
tz = z(i)-z(1);
```

This is because the transform `trans` that you apply to the point is an *absolute* transform. In other words, the transform is applied to the *original position* of the point on each loop iteration, not to the *most recent position*.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. You are right (I really thought that the translation vector was applied to the most recent position). Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing on [@gnovice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362954/3d-animation-plot-with-the-hgtransform-command-in-matlab/6363142#6363142)'s answer, you could take that part out of the loop to become something like:

```
%# calculate translation steps  (absolute with respect to original location)
trans = bsxfun(@minus, [x(:) y(:) z(:)], [x(1) y(1) z(1)]);

%# translate point
for i=1:size(trans,1)
    set(ht, 'Matrix',makehgtform('translate',trans(i,:)));
    pause(0.01);
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your interesting solution. Doubtless, asking this question has been an enrichening experience. Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

As gnovice said, in your code you're setting the absolute transform. You can make your transform relative by multiplying instead of setting. Like this:

```
tx = x(i)-x(i-1);
ty = y(i)-y(i-1);
tz = z(i)-z(i-1);
trans = makehgtform('translate'),[tx ty tz]),
set(ht,'Matrix',get(ht,'Matrix')*trans);
```

Multiplying the current value of the Matrix property by trans lets you accumulate your transform step by step.

Comment: I am grateful for your answer. I am not used to handle the hgtransform function but this question has allowed me to know more about it. Cheers.